# Алгоритм создание вложенный запросов в MySql

Tags: mysql

Всем привет. Есть вот такое вот задание

Узнать в каких темах оставлял сообщения автор тема "От дениса", ниже решение

```
SELECT topic_name FROM topics WHERE id_topic IN
(SELECT id_topic FROM posts WHERE id_author IN
(SELECT id_author FROM topics WHERE topic_name = "от Дениса")
)
```

Смотрю на него и все понятно как все работает. Но вот как изначально составить алгоритм вложенного запроса? как бы вы составляли алгоритм данной задачи? с какого конца начинать?

Comment: `WHERE id_author=1 IN` - ошибка тут есть.

Comment: Всё это хорошо... вот только DDL - где они?

Comment: @Akina DDL? можно расшифрофку

Comment: Data Definition Language. SQL-код создания/модификации/удаления объекта БД (в данном случае - `CREATE TABLE`). https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-data-definition.html